# Importing distro to compute engine

Tags: linux, google-compute-engine, distro

I want to import [Linufix](https://www.linufix.org) to the compute engine.

1. Anyone knows the steps to import a distro from the ISO image file?
2. Will it give me X window access to load the GUI from remote or just an ssh console?

Thanks

Comment: you might want to move this question to Serverfault, here you have [more information](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image) to import the image, unless you install VNC or another tool with GUI interface enabled you only will be able to access via SSH.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly create a GCE image from a ISO. Instead you have to do a minimal install, and then make an image from that installed system.  This process can be a little complex, so the easiest solution is to use software like [Hashicorp Packer](https://www.packer.io/) to do it for you.